# Equivalent function not found for ERROR_PROCEDURE(),ERROR_LINE(),ERROR_MESSAGE()

Tags: database, postgresql

We have certain functions in sql server such as`ERROR_PROCEDURE()`, `ERROR_LINE()`, `ERROR_MESSAGE()`. I am unable to find any equivalent 
functions in postgresql. I am new to postgres and presently migrating from sql server to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL equivalent would be [`RAISE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html). E.g.:

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Something went horribly wrong';
```

Comment: Like in case of oracle we can capture and insert the error code and error message into an error log table

for example:

exception
       when others then
  insert into my_error_log_tbl(error_code,error_message,error_reason)
  values (SQLCODE,SQLERRM,'Some thing went horribly wrong');
end;